# Deleting overlap between two polyline layers in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, overlapping-features, remove

I have two stream layers and they overlap, I want to delete this overlap on one layer so I do not repeat any information.

How do I do this?

I can only seem to find information regarding polygons.

Answer (score 2):

Use topology tools on the data to identify overlaps and crossings.  Then edit the data where topology identifies errors.  Here is [a link to](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/topologies/topology-in-arcgis.htm#GUID-DDC1DD90-E5DA-4457-A35F-8DBB9E85DE74) using topology.  You will see in the topology rules section that one rule includes *Stream lines cannot overlap and must connect to one another at their endpoints*.

Comment: Thank you for that. When I select the Topology Rules tool (or the Create Topology tool) my dataset will not show, it shows the GDB, and I have tried saving it outside of the GDB but it still wont show, do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to create to topology outside of a feature dataset?  Your data is inside of a geodatabase but not inside a feature dataset inside of that geodatabase? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/feature-datasets/an-overview-of-working-with-feature-datasets.htm  You might want to start a new question. Running dialogs anger the mediators:)